# angular 7 how to access element by id defined in parent component from child component template

Tags: angular7, primeng

I am using primeng multiSelect control in the child component. i want this to be appended to the element defined in the parent component as shown above.
the above code failed when i run npm run build:prod. it can't access popupContent in the child. can anyone help how to access the parent element in the child component?

```
**Parent component:**

                <tbody app-sg-add-edit-subline-agg (sublineSave)="onSublineSave($event)" #popupContent>   
                </tbody>

**sg-add-edit-subline-agg component:**
                <p-multiSelect optionLabel="name"
                   [options]="sublines"
                   formControlName="name"
                   [appendTo]="popupContent">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone help how to access the parent element in the child component?

[*The Example shown below is from the Angular Documents*](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

The parent will need to send the data using the `@Input()` functionality.
However, there are other ways to pass information from Child to Parent and Parent to Child like using a `service`. This is just a basic example.

**Parent Component**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
import { HEROES } from './hero';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-hero-parent',
      template: `
        <h2>{{master}} controls {{heroes.length}} heroes</h2>
        <app-hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
          [hero]="hero"
          [master]="master">
        </app-hero-child>
      `
    })
    export class HeroParentComponent {
      heroes = HEROES;
      master = 'Master';
    }
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
    <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

We are using a reference template variable to obtain a reference of the parent using #popupComponent. And then we pass it to the child as an @Input() property.

**Parent component:**

```
<tbody app-sg-add-edit-subline-agg 
       (sublineSave)="onSublineSave($event)" 
       #popupContent [popupContent]="popupContent">   
</tbody>
```

**sg-add-edit-subline-agg.component.html:**

```
<p-multiSelect optionLabel="name"
[options]="sublines"
formControlName="name"
[appendTo]="popupContent">
```

***Make sure to add the @Input property in sg-add-edit-subline-agg.component.ts***

```
@Input() popupContent;
```

StackBlitz with a simpler example of above concept: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-parent-child?file=app%2Fapp.component.html